# Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

Tags: linux-mint, gtk

I keep getting this error in the terminal whenever a GUI App or popup appears

```
Gtk-Message: 17:55:00.609: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
```

I used to have "appmenu-gtk-module" installed but i later uninstalled it. Now I keep getting this error when i run a gui application from the terminal, or an IDE.

OS : Linux Mint 21.1

Comment: "I used to have "appmenu-gtk-module" installed but i later uninstalled it."  The seemingly obvious answer would be to **reinstall appmenu-gtk-module**.  For what reason did you uninstall appmenu-gtk-module?

Comment: @RonJohn Because We don't need it anymore. Is there anyway to check where is this hook comes from? I tried to check GTK_MODULES, seems not working

Comment: @mintkat by any chance, could you check the content of gsettings and xfconf? for key /Gtk/Modules = appmenu-gtk-module. If it's there, you can remove it. I just test from xfce, it gone, and the error went away.